# How to use dgv to select from rows using checkboxes to insert specific records into database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i was wondering if anyone could explain or point me to a suitable tutorial which explains how i would go about using datagridviews to insert the rows selected using checkboxes into the database. To explain a bit more understanding i'm trying to create an add (food) products feature which would use a dgv to select its included ingredients from my sql server database table of ingredients.

So far I've the dgv bringing up the list of ingredients as well as the checkboxes displaying working, i also already know how to write an insert sql script but i cant figure out how to use the checkboxes as the deciding factor in which rows are inserted. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  You need to do your own research (you'll learn stuff).  Then when you get stuck on a programming problem, post a question about it.  MSDN is a good place to start.

Comment: Jesus, i've never seen a website that hates noobs quite this much. That was as passive as i could ask for one bit of code i couldn't find myself, it took a couple of seconds to answer and you still complain... You all expect everyone to just be able to find and learn every single thing, i don't think you remember how hard it can be to figure out this stuff when you're new

Comment: and believe me you all tell me that this site "isn't here to do your work for you" when i am more specific lol

Comment: `This is not a tutorial site. You need to do your own research.`  You'd know that if you read [Ask] and took the [Tour] as you agreed to when you joined.  There it states: *`Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`*  and also *`Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`*.  No one here hates novices, just broad, vague, OT questions.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" thats what i have done before and people complain lol. Tbh i thought asking for tutorials would be less work but fair enough if it's in the rules

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can check line-to-line if your field is checked.
SUpposing the CheckBox is the first column:

Example:

```
   Dim TotalRecords As Integer = Yourgrid.RowCount - 1
   For i as integer = 0 To TotalRecords
          if Yourgrid.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True
               ' add this record to dabatase
          End If
   Next
```

PS: you may also change the instruction above to utilize the column name:

```
    if Yourgrid.Rows(i).Cells("MyCheckBoxColumn").Value = True
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect i haven't tested it yet but i will soon :)

Comment: Ok @JoshStrachan, good luck. And don't forget to vote if it attend your needs. Best regards!

Comment: I will do, dont worry